# VBA to collapse entire pivot table except last entry

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have macro to refresh the pivot data - however, upon refresh all the fields with the 'latest' data become expanded as by inherent design. I'd like to collapse all the rows with the exception of the last, and latest, entry.

Any assistance would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you by chance find the macro recorder helpful?

Comment: Just tried using it, first step collapsing all fields of the pivot... here's what I had, which didn't do anything

Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
' a
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("Date"). _
        ShowDetail = False
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here...

```
Dim pT As PivotTable
Dim pF As PivotField

Set pT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WorksheetName").PivotTables(1)
With pT
    For Each pF In pT.RowFields
        pF.DrillTo pF.Name
    Next pF
End With
```